# AES Decryption: if the decrypted file has a typo the Application crashes

Tags: c#, xml, aes

So I recently added encryption to my application.
Every time I start the application, the program checks if there are file to encrypt in a certain directory, encrypts them and then moves them to another folder.
Then it decrypts all the files in said folder, deserializes them and shows them to the user.
My problem is that if any of the files to encrypt has a typo, on deserialization it fails, and instead of logging the error and moving on it gives me the error 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.' and then crashes.

My encryption:

```
                    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
                    FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.xml");
                    if(Files.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (FileInfo f in Files)
                        {
                            using (FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(f.FullName, FileMode.Open))
                            {
                                var newFile = dir + "\\" + f.Name;
                                newFile = newFile.Replace("\\Decrypted", "");
                                using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create))
                                {
                                    // Perform encryption
                                    Aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                                    ICryptoTransform encryptor = Aes.CreateEncryptor();
                                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsOutput, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            fsInput.CopyTo(cs);
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception e)
                                        {
                                            _logger.Warn(e);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

My Decryption:

```
            using FileStream myFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
            {
                using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
                {
                    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    aes.Key = _dec.GetKey();
                    aes.IV = _dec.GetIv();
                    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(myFile, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        try
                        {
                            return Deserialize<T>(cs);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            _logger.Warn(e, "Reading XML file {0} failed", path);
                            return default;
                        }
                }
            }
```

The error is showed on the 'return default;' in the try-catch.

I have tried specifying the padding in multiple points of the process adding the CryptoStream FlushLastBlock and other possible fixes I found in other posts but nothing works.

Comment: That `using FileStream myFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);` syntax looks a little suspect.

Comment: In what sense? It hasn't created any problems outside of the case of the typo, and even then its not causing any errors.

Comment: Well, fair, it's apparently an _`using` declaration_, but you should get rid of the misleading braces after it, since it's not really tied to the block.

Comment: Where are you getting the key and IV from? You don't seem to be setting it in the encryption, so it will be random.

Comment: The key and iv are static values set inside of my application, stored in a Decrypter class.

Comment: The error seems to be that after decrypting the file and failing on the deserialization, it tries to the re-decrypt the already decrypted file.

Comment: You are not setting the key and IV on the encryption side, so it's been encrypted with a random key.

Comment: No I am is set higher in the class where the files are encrypted.
Again its not a problem of decrypting the files, as when there are no typos the files are decrypted correctly.

Comment: the using statement should have curly brackets.  The error may not be in the code posted.  You are returning default which is null and the issue may be in the calling method when trying to process a null.

Comment: Yhea, that seems to be the issue. I tried settings some breakpoints inside of the RinjdaelManagedTransform class, and the issue seems to be that on a null default value the last byte of the output buffer exceeds the allowed lenght or InputBlockSize.
I tried manually flushing the last block but that results in the same error.

Comment: Post the code that calls the method. You need to check for null and the stop processing.